# How to display a message continuously with infinite for loop?

Tags: for-loop, tcl

My TCL Script:

I wrote the following TCL script, using infinite while loop to display some message to a user.

```
set a "Please Dont disturb... script is running...!!!!!!!!!!!"
while {1} {
    puts $a
    after 3000
}
```

Above scripts works as expected. Could anyone help me rewrite the above script using `for` loop?

Comment: sounds like a candidate for tdwtf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set a "Please Dont disturb... script is running...!!!!!!!!!!!"

for { } { true } {  } {
 puts $a
 after 3000
}
```

Comment: In general, `for {} {true} {} { .... }` would be enough, though it's not a case that the `for` compiler is optimised for.

Comment: @DonalFellows, Updated my answer. Thanks Donal. Glad to learn one more thing from you. :)